# Change storyboard or scenes on storyboard dynamically

Tags: xcode, ios5, xcode-storyboard

I want to programing an app for iPhone with XCode 4.2. I use a tabbar for switching through the functions of this app.
I need to "situations": One "situation" is logged in tabbar, the second "situation" is the login tabbar. So two ideas come in my mind: Either I use two storyboards and use the storyboard dynamically or I use just one storyboard and use two scenes (login and logged in) and assign the viewcontroller dynamically. But I don't know how I can program this..
What do you mean what I have to do? How I can do this?

Thanks for answer :)

Answer (score 0):

please try this. I hope that it will help you.

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="Trainning.animation"
x:Name="Window"
Title="animation"
Width="640" Height="480">
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="one_in_all">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="btn_animation_1">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFF0F0EA"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="#FF038529"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="#FFF0F0EA"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Button x:Name="btn_animation_1" Content="Animation1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="54" Margin="187,133,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64" Click="btn_animation_1_Click" />
    <Button x:Name="btn_animation_2" Content="Animation2" Height="54" Margin="310,133,258,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btn_animation_2_Click" />
</Grid>
```

in code behind

```
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

public partial class animation : Window
{
    string Name;
    public animation()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        // Insert code required on object creation below this point.
    }

    private void btn_animation_1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        Name = button.Name;
        Animation_In_All();
    }

    public void Animation_In_All()
    {
        Storyboard SB = (Storyboard)(FindResource("one_in_all"));
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(SB.Children[0], Name);           
        SB.Begin();
    }

    private void btn_animation_2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        Name = button.Name;
        Animation_In_All();
    }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with iOS storyboards.